# C# Async StreamReader and put in ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

Im building a tool that read data from a remote server and put it in a listbox.
The tool take inputs from a TXT file to pass as GET to the remote server then take result back in a listbox.
Example:
I've a list in TXT with following lines (they are over 12.000 lines actually and it will grow):
-Foo
-Abc
-Def

So the tool for each line call the remote server:

```
http://remote-server.com/variable=Foo
*GET RESULT BACK AND PUT IN LISTBOX*
http://remote-server.com/variable=Abc
*GET RESULT BACK AND PUT IN LISTBOX*
http://remote-server.com/variable=Def
*GET RESULT BACK AND PUT IN LISTBOX*
```

It works fine, the problem is that it require lot of time because the list, as said before, contains over 12.000 lines and make my tool FREEZED till the process is end, so I wanna do it in Async and see in real time in my listbox the results and don't get the tools freezed for 15mins!!

Following my code:

```
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("List.txt");
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
        string urlAddress = ("http://remote-server.com/variable=" + line);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            if(data=="")
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("0");
                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
            }
            else { 
            listBox1.Items.Add(data);
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            }
        }
        }
```

Since, I really don't know where to start. Im trying to read few tutorials but I really can't understand how to apply async to this operations, I never worked with it.
I tryed to replace the streamreader with:

```
string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
```

but it doesen't work.
Looking for a way :-)
Thanks to everybody!
Wish you all a great day.

G.

Comment: Can you apply more context, I ask because this implementation won't benefit from Async.

Comment: Thanks for your support Greg. What you mean with "Apply more Context"? Thanks Greg.

Comment: Is this a winforms application? I've used the background worker to update a listview in this manner. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Put the process in a background worker and it will not freeze your main thread.  You can add a splash screen or something to indicate it is loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `HttpClient`, which is much easier to use with `await`:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var reader = new StreamReader("List.txt"))
{
  var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
  while (line != null)
  {
    var urlAddress = ("http://remote-server.com/variable=" + line);
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(urlAddress);
    listBox1.Items.Add(result == "" ? "0" : result);

    line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Stephen, thank you so much! I tryed your code but I get an error saying: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task". Thanks!!

Comment: @GCiri add `async` to your method. eg `public async Task DoSomething()`

Comment: You are right and IT WORKS GREAT!!!! Thank you Stephan, simple clean and professional. Thank you so much, wish you a great day! ;-) G.

Comment: Hey Stephen, I see you are very expert in Async, can you tell me how to stop the async process? Im trying with CANCEL TOKEN but without results. Thanks again Stephan ;-) G.

Comment: @GCiri: Yes, you would use a `CancellationToken`, which your asynchronous code can just pass into `GetStringAsync`.

Comment: Hello Stephen, thank you again for your support. Its much if I ask for an example? Im really in difficulty to use Async. Thanks Stephen!!

Comment: @GCiri: You add a `CancellationToken` parameter to your method and pass it to `GetStringAsync` - really, that's it. If you have a followup question about cancellation feel free to post it.